# How to add a text or button through JavaScript in this condition?

Tags: javascript, twitter, console, inspect

I have accessed some code from Twitter web page https://twitter.com/explore through `inspect`. This code is given as below.

```
 <span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">Sign up</span>
```

I am trying to add one text i.e. "Dark Mode" on https://twitter.com/explore web page by using JavaScript.

From above code, I fetched `class` and put into following JavaCcript code.

```
var x = document.createElement('p');
var t = document.createTextNode("Dark Mode");
x.appendChild(t);
document.querySelector(".css-901oao css-16my406 r-1qd0xha r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0").appendChild(x);
```

I am using console on web page (in inspect) and trying to add javascript code `appendChild` in order to add text "Dark Mode" on Twitter web page, but it doesn't work.
It gives me following error.

```
  VM1667:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at <anonymous>:4:87
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Screen Shot]

Above is the Twitter web page, where I am trying to add text - "Dark Mode" through console, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solutions

```
  var x = document.createElement("P");
  var t = document.createTextNode("Dark Mode.");
  x.appendChild(t);
  document.querySelector('.css-1dbjc4n.r-1777fci.r-1mf7evn').appendChild(x);
```

#### Proved

[prnt.sc/rnxcth](http://prnt.sc/rnxcth)

Hopes that it help. Happy coding.

Comment: I try over my twitter, it's work. Here is the proved. https://prnt.sc/rnus5y

Comment: Hello, If possible please try on this page without log in and show me - https://twitter.com/explore

Comment: I have again updated screen shot. It does not work there. It gives error - ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
    at <anonymous>:4:59```

Comment: Great! It worked. But I needed to add dot instead of space in class name. That I didn't know. Thanks.

Comment: Please format your answer properly, so that I can accept it.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Happy to hear that it work. Happy coding